# How can I run Perl on web servers?

Tags: perl

I am very new to Perl and I wonder how to run it on webservers and all. (or if it can)

Comment: Perl can certainly run on webservers, but more likely so on those with Unix-like operating systems. It is used for CGI scripting.

Comment: Check this out for mod_perl : http://perl.apache.org/docs/1.0/guide/getwet.html

Comment: Zaki, the current version of `mod_perl` is 2. Proper link: http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/intro/start_fast.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The three commonest options are:

- [mod_perl](http://perl.apache.org/)
- [FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/)
- [CGI](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3875)

I'd recommend FastCGI for good performance without massive complication.

The new kid on the block is [PSGI/Plack](http://plackperl.org/), which I can't comment on as I haven't found time to look at it properly.

There are various web frameworks (such as [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/)) which can do a lot of the heavy lifting involved in building a web application for you. Most can be accessed with more than one of the above methods (e.g. Catalyst supports all four).

Answer (score 2):

1) cgi, infact any program can run behind the server.
2) mod-perl

Answer (score 2):

You can even run Perl as a webserver :)

For eq: [`Continuity`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Continuity/)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Continuity;

Continuity->new->loop;

sub main {
    my $request = shift;
    $request->print( '<p>Hello world</p>' );
}
```

You can then looking into doing a [`Reverse Proxy`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) in front of these.

/I3az/

Answer (score 2):

You clearly want to use PSGI/Plack to deploy your Perl application. This is the way to go in 2010, you should not go another way.

PSGI/Plack lets you deploy the application under any webserver you like, see http://plackperl.org for details.

You'll also have to choose an application framework that supports PSGI. There are many; among them is Dancer a micro-framework designed to be as effortless as possible for the developer.

See http://dancer.sukria.net for details.