# HTML- pass data to perl script

Tags: html, perl

I want to pass data from an html form to a Perl script, execute the script and display result on HTML page again.

Comment: This is not really a specific question. You should be able to get plenty of examples from searching on google. I suspect this question will be closed as it is so vague.

Comment: Your question is very general, and it appears that you have done no research to try to answer the question yourself.

Comment: I tried.. when I use action: ....pl, it prints the perl script on webpage, rather than executing the script

Comment: Try the CGI module from [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org)

Comment: I have used CGI module..

Comment: You need a web server. You can install something like Apache or there are several Perl based web servers on CPAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass data from HTML to a program directly, you would normally submit a form to a URI and configure the webserver to pass the submitted data to a program and the program's output back to the webbrowser.

There are [several common ways to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107356/how-can-i-run-perl-on-web-servers/2107359#2107359)