# What servers are suitable for Perl on a development box?

Tags: perl, development-environment

I'm maintaining a simple web site written in Perl in my copious free time, and I don't want do my coding on the live website any more, instead checking if the changes work on a local machine first.

As far as I can tell, the web site runs on apache.

Should I install apache on my local machine, or are there simpler (but well documented!) options more suited to a development box?

Related question: [How can I run Perl on web servers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107356/how-can-i-run-perl-on-web-servers) , but seems to be talking about a production box, not a development box.

Comment: I've run Apache instances on local machines to accomplish this: xampp for Windows and a Linux Mint VM using Oracle VM VirtualBox.  Both worked well for Perl scripting...

Comment: Would this question be better answered on http://programmers.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: That depends on the code you're writing. If you're developing your webapps with Plack, you can develop against Starman (or Twiggy on win32) without worrying about cloning the production environment.

Answer (score 2):

[XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)  is an excellent package for precisely this purpose.  It includes Apache, MySQL, PHP, Perl, and other tools, all pre-configured to run on your local machine.  I use it for WordPress, but I expect that it would be equally good for Perl CGI development.

I use it on Windows.  It is also available for Linux and Mac.

*Hat tip to Kenosis, who mentioned XAMPP first.  I didn't see that at the time.*

Comment: I second that. Using it for small Perl CGI things on Win 7 that I develop at home and push out to a Debian box. I do have an ActivePerl installation instead of the Perl package, though. I recommend the smaller XAMPP lite archive and ActivePerl. It's easy to set up and has less clutter.

Comment: @simbabque, I used ActivePerl in the past and was happy with it, but I now prefer Strawberry Perl because it is open source and includes a C compiler environment that lets you compile standard modules from CPAN.  The latter feature would be especially helpful if you were developing on Windows for a Linux production environment.

Comment: That makes sense. I have never tried Strawberry so I wouldn't know. But I'm using Komodo, so ActivePerl is the obvious choice.